# How to render gender select view like this - React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I would like to know how to render gender selection view like this...[image]

Once I clicked on Male I want to render Yellow Image (Checked) and Once I clicked on Female I want to make Male Image to Default and Female Image in to Yellow Image (Checked).

Note - I have 4 separate images

eg - Male_Checked / Male_Unchecked / Female_Checked / Female_Unchecked (PNG)

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that returns an image based on selected value like below.

```
getImageForGender(gender) {

    if (gender == this.state.selectedGender) {
        return (gender == "male") ? Images.Male_Checked : Images.Female_Checked;
    }
    else {
        return (gender == "male") ? Images.Male_UnChecked : Images.Female_UnChecked;
    }
}
```

Than you can use this function to assign the image in ImageView like:

```
<Image source={{getImageForGender("male")}} />
<Image source={{getImageForGender("female")}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer !

```
{this.state.male_checked == 0 ? (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({male_checked: 1, female_checked: 0});
                }}
                style={styles.btn}>
                <Image style={styles.img} source={Images.BMI_MALE} />
                <Text>Male</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ) : (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({male_checked: 0});
                }}
                style={styles.btn}>
                <Image style={styles.img} source={Images.BMI_MALE_CHECKED} />
                <Text>Male</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}

            {this.state.female_checked == 0 ? (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({female_checked: 1, male_checked: 0});
                }}
                style={styles.btn}>
                <Image style={styles.img} source={Images.BMI_FEMALE} />
                <Text>Female</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ) : (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({female_checked: 0});
                }}
                style={styles.btn}>
                <Image style={styles.img} source={Images.BMI_FEMALE_CHECKED} />
                <Text>Female</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
```

Comment: You might want to replace your image with icon. This [React Native Vector Icon](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) provides you a few sets which contains lots of different icons. You can customize color, size, etc ... by passing `style` to icon component.